# Solving an expression with two integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am reading an economics paper, where the authors use a definition as ;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}a+f\left(x\left(\tau\right)\right)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a+f\left(x\left(\tau\right)\right)d\tau}d\tau=1
 $$

where $a$ is a constant term and $f$ is a function in terms of $x(\tau)$ ;

I tried to use integration by parts in order to solve it but as there is a second term with integral with exponential, I could not solve it.

How can I find that is equal to $1$ ?

Any hints or suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not a complete answer !**

I think there is probably a little mistake in your formula and I think that your post lacks a bit of informations about $f$ and $x$ to conclude. But here is an idea that you could find useful.

So I think that the formula is $$\int_{0}^{\infty}a+f\left(x\left(\tau\right)\right)e^{-\int_{0}^{\tau}a+f\left(x\left(t\right)\right)dt}d\tau$$

Let $v(\tau)=\int_{0}^{\tau}a+f\left(x\left(t\right)\right)dt$, then $v'(\tau)=a+f(x(\tau))$.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}a+f\left(x\left(\tau\right)\right)e^{-\int_{0}^{\tau}a+f\left(x\left(t\right)\right)dt}d\tau=\int_{0}^{\infty}v'(\tau)e^{-v(t)}d\tau=-[e^{-v(\tau)}]_0^{\infty}=-[e^{-\int_{0}^{\tau}a+f\left(x\left(t\right)\right)dt}]_0^{\infty}=-e^{-\int_{0}^{\infty}a+f\left(x\left(t\right)\right)dt}+1$$

So the point would be to prove that $\lim_{y \to \infty}\int_0^{y}a+f(x(t))dt=\infty$. But you need some information about $f$ and $x$ to prove that.